# How to enhance sensitivity in one class classification if you are getting high accuracy and specificity but low sensitivity?

Tags: classification

If you are getting low sensitivity and high specifcity with one class classfication then how to overcome this problem?

e.g. positive data is divided into 90 % training and 10% testing. Further add fare amount of negative data with 10% positive testing data (use only positive data for training because of one class classification problem).

Since, you have to decide threshold in one class classification by rejection of 10% or few percentage most deviating training data. So, there is possibilty that your 10% testing lies in the rejection region. So, it leads to low sensitivity.

How to resolve this issue? I stucked on this "by high accuracy but low sensitivity".

Comment: Some context would be nice.

Comment: Thanks Lister. I have worked with microRNA dataset and this problem is well known for one class classification in microRNA dataset.